# SEO in React based SPA

Tags: reactjs, react-router, seo, single-page-application

I have a single page application built using React library (Create React App is used). And I have different routes inside the application which I am resolving using React Router, for instance `http://<domain-name>.com/faq`. Server side rendering is not used and right now I don't have a possibility to use it.

I want inner pages of that application to be indexed by Google search engine. In order to do that I did the next things:

- Make inner pages (for instance `/faq` page) accessible via their routes
- Created `sitemap.xml` file inside `public` folder so that when the application is built Create React app puts this files into `/build` folder right after `index.html` file

Sitemap file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset
  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9  
  http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.<domain-name>.com</loc>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </url>

  <url>
    <loc>https://www.<domain-name>.com/faq</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Where `<domain-name>` is a real domain name. I omited the rest of the pages here for the sake of simplicity.

But unfortunately those pages are not being indexed by Google search engine even a week after I deployed this application. So I decided to use Google search console (`https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome`) and found that all of my inner pages are not found.

[image]

So my question is how to make pages listed in the sitemap file to be indexed by Google search engine?

NOTE: I am not sure if it's important or not, but when I open FAQ page in the browser and open Chrome dev tools, I see that there is a request to the document `/faq` and 404 response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google should be able to index React applications. If it cannot do it and doesn't see your routes, it's possible that you have an error in your app. If it works in a browser, something still can cause an error for Google. You can use for example [Google Pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) at least to be sure it can render your app properly.

Alternatively you can do dynamic rendering -- generating a plain HTML on the server for bots. Here is how to do it with Nginx and Apache https://trackabi.com/blog/single-page-application-seo But, again, Google can crawl React SPAs, there is probably an error.